# Is the age that Kirk becomes Captain different in TOS and the reboot film?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009

How old is James T. Kirk when he becomes captain in TOS and in the reboot film? Do the ages differ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, his/their ages are different, 25 in the reboot and 34 in TOS.

> By decree of Starfleet Order 28455 soon after, Kirk won a permament
>   field commission as captain and Enterprise commander despite his young
>   age at 25—nine years younger than his Prime counterpart when he won
>   his captain's stripes.

From http://www.startrek.com/database_article/kirk-2009

Comment: I thought that TOS Kirk was 37 but your math is indesputable.