# When is Star Trek: Discovery set?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

The series *Star Trek: Discovery*, due to be released in early 2017, will be the first new *Star Trek* series since *Enterprise*. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Discovery):

> Set to premiere on CBS in January 2017 before moving to All Access,
>   the series will introduce new characters to the Star Trek franchise,
>   and will not be related to the 2016 film Star Trek Beyond.

The same article mentions that it will take place in the original timeline.

Has there been any confirmation of what year the series is set in? Is it before or after *Star Trek: Beyond*?

Comment: Most likely in the peroid of Enterprise C. We dont know much about that ship or its captains. I have read somwhere that is will be similar to True Detective, where you have a different crew every saeson. Cant fint the article now so thats why im making it a coment in stead of an answer.

Comment: @Cherubel: prediction noted.

Comment: Nicely done on your future taxonomist badge :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## 2255

Bryan Fuller has revealed that it will be set in about 2255 in the Prime Timeline ([source](http://trekcore.com/blog/2016/08/bryan-fuller-reveals-long-awaited-star-trek-discovery-details/)).

To put that into the context of the Prime Timeline, that puts it about 100 years after *Enterprise* and 10 years before *TOS*.

In terms of the Reboot Timeline, it occurs 22 years after Nero's arrival, the same year that [Kirk joins Starfleet](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/kirk-kelvin) and we see the *Enterprise* being constructed in Iowa in *Star Trek* (2009); and well before the events of *Beyond*.

Comment: Huh, given the fairly different-looking starship I would have figured it was set before they created the [Constitution class](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Constitution_class) that Kirk's Enterprise belonged to, but this would put it right around the time of the flashback scenes of ["The Menagerie"](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Menagerie,_Part_I_(episode)) when Captain Pike was captain of the Enterprise. Wonder if any Constitution class ships will make cameos, or Captain Pike himself...

Comment: +1 but disappointing --- I had read in several places that it would be set around the time of the Enterprise C, and this seemed to be the impression most fans had in Vegas at the 50th Anniversary Celebration.  I trust this announcement, but after all of the reboot films, it would have been nice to see a time period *after* *TOS*.

Comment: Personally I'm disappointed that it's another prequel. It somewhat limits some of the stories they can do.  The Romulans were unseen for many years before Balance of Power, so that rather suggests we won't see the Romulans in this show. So too any alien race that the enterprise met first - Tholians, etc.

Yeah, they can get around that by not reporting any incidents or something, but that's a bit hack.

Comment: @VBartilucci There are rumours that each season will have a different crew, and speculation that that means a different time period. So it may be that the Enterprise C era will be the focus of Season 2. The emphasis on a single character in the quote from Fuller also backs up the idea of a more long-form storyline, rather than lots of "monster of the week", which may help sidestep the issues with races that are not discovered yet.

Comment: There were also rumors that every season of Heroes would have a completely different cast, and that each year would be a brand new story.  But then the current cast got popular, and that plan largely went out the door.  

The first rule of television, as coined by Ernie Kovacs, is "beat it to death if it succeeds".  If they get a cast that's a hit, you'll likely not be able to getthem out of the network's hands with explosives.

Comment: I know Amanda Grayson will be in it, and probably Sarek as it's not ten years before TOS, so Spock will have been born.

Comment: Oops, I mean 'set' ten years before!

Comment: The female Lt Commander in command could be Number One, Pike's first officer! That'd be interesting

Comment: @IMSoP Fuller later ruled out the 'new cast per season' idea saying that they weren't going to do that.

Comment: `In terms of the Reboot Timeline, it occurs 33 years after Nero's arrival, the same year as Kirk joins Starfleet` - [This indicates reboot-Kirk was 17 when he joined Starfleet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(film)#Plot), and [this says he was 25 when promoted to Captain](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/43331/2242)

Comment: I was hoping what they'd do is set it in the 28th+ century and then travel back in time to other points in history so we could see what the crews of the various ships were doing after x period, expand the lore, and get a new crew... Or do a Voth leaving Earth series which would be so cool ^.^

Comment: @Durakken : That would have been nice.  I love *TOS*, but we really ought to stop making prequels, especially ones set in or around the *TOS* time period. Fans have been consistently calling for something set after *Voyager*, but no one seems to be listening....

Comment: @Praxis STO takes place after Voyager and it is supposedly canon ^.^

Comment: @Durakken : I've never played *Star Trek Online*, but I have some awareness of its plot points.  But I want a television series, not a game!  :-(

Comment: @Praxis indeed. I also don't think it's very good due to them trying to make things more into an action oriented thing.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I'm curious to see if we encounter Captain Robert April, captain before Pike

Comment: @Durakken - According to [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/31115/22250) STO is not canon--if you have some other info suggesting it is, consider adding a new answer to that question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that this is really a spoiler, per se, but the *Enterprise* under [Christopher Pike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Pike_(Star_Trek)) (mentioned only) appears in the final moments of the Season 1 
[image]

Given that [The Cage](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Cage_(episode)) took place in 2254, this is in keeping with the TOS timeline

Comment: ...I need to catch up but if that isn't evidence of this show *not* being Prime timeline, I don't know what is. That looks like some crazy mashup of the TOS and Refit. The refit design has no place 10 years prior to TOS.

Comment: @NKCampbell It's hard to say. Other than the dressed-up lighting, it's not terribly dissimilar to the original. [It's no reboot Enterprise, tho](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-SRvedYdQtEo/TVfoA5IfX1I/AAAAAAAACdk/aAPtsXMEoNc/s1600/Picture%2B012.jpg). Oh, and they ended with the TOS theme. We'll have to see what S2 brings with this. Could be good, could be very, very bad.